# Excel to Javascript web conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, web

I have an Excel sheet calculation I'm trying to convert to a Javascript with web output. I'm rather new to Javascript but Im having some trouble with a function of the sheet I'm trying to implement.

The sheet is a Helium volume calculator that will take a given balloon type, multiply by a quantity then suggest the best value for which helium tanks are required to fill the given volume.

Here's the spreadsheet for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11EanU_iEr5QIxggyQNjxObFbHRg_77_TXsLQ-zhmtUY/edit?usp=sharing

Here's my JSFiddle attempt at a short and simple web app:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLnv9xLj/41/

```
var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);

$('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var

    tanks = {
      0: {
        name: 'HEL550',
        volume: 292
      },
      1: {
        name: 'HEL450',
        volume: 225
      },
      2: {
        name: 'HEL250',
        volume: 125
      },
      3: {
        name: 'HEL160',
        volume: 125
      },
      4: {
        name: 'HEL110',
        volume: 55
      },
      5: {
        name: 'HEL50',
        volume: 27.5
      },
      6: {
        name: 'BT 326502',
        volume: 14.9
      },

      7: {
        name: 'BT 306472',
        volume: 8.9
      }
    },

    balloonModel = $('balloon_model').value,
    qantity = $('qty').value,
    finalResult = balloonModel * qantity,
    finalResultRounded = finalResult.toFixed(2),
    tankCalc = tanks[7].name;

  $('result').value = finalResultRounded;
  $('tankyouneed').value = tankCalc;


}, false);
```

Basic volume calculation is easy enough and working. But I can't get my head around trying to use an array and loop to do the other stuff.

In the spreadsheet all the balloon types are listed but I really only need to chose a single one at a time, hence the dropdown. I don't need the tank calculations displayed, just which tank to chose as suggested by the spreadsheet result. To the right are 3 tank suggestions: actual tank(s) needed, maximum transportability or one-time use for those who don't want to ever buy again.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I understand. You need a loop to find the best, second etc. tank result.
There is something wrong in my code but i hope you understand my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLnv9xLj/42/

```
   for(var i = 0; i < tanks.length; i++){
         var tank = tanks[i];
       console.log(tank);
       if(tank.volume >= finalResult){
            if(
             first_tank.name !== '' &&
            (first_tank.volume - finalResult) > (tank.volume - finalResult)
            ){
             first_tank = tank;
          }else{
            first_tank = tank;
          }
       }
    }
```

I loop every single tank and check the volume. If the higher or equal to my result need it put it as first_tank. Maybe the name best_tank is better. Before i check the first_tank. Is it not empty i check the need volume and volume of the tank. Is this (volume of the tank - volume you need) less then the (volume of the first_tank - volume you need) it put it as first_tank or better best_tank.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I generally see what you're attempting but I'm still not getting the gist of it.. I'm not sure why you're setting a first and second tank as 0 for comparators though... If you check the spreadsheet you will see that it checks the total volume of the given requirement and selects the correct tank(s) and the quantities required. If I exceed a volume, (say I require 5000 of the Latex 9" round) the sheet shows a volume of 1250 cubic feet and thus suggests 4 HEL550 tanks plus one HEL160 tank.